# How can I namespace functions, but still keep them treeshakeable?

Tags: javascript, namespaces, tree-shaking

Let's say I have:

```
export class HelloWorld {
  static readonly sayHello = () => {
    console.log('hi')
  }
  static readonly sayGoodbye = () => {
    console.log('goodbye')
  }
}
```

which I could call with `HelloWorld.sayHello()`. But then in my client, the dead code of `sayGoodbye` is not eliminated by rollup, I tried with `ng build --prod` with Angular 6. What would work is to have

```
export function sayHello() {
  console.log('hi')
}
export function sayGoodbye() {
  console.log('goodbye')
}
```

and then in the client code directly calling `sayHello()`. In my opinion this is a little less readable, since I'm not immediately getting context where this function is coming from.

So my question is, is there a way we can have both, namespacing AND treeshaking?

Comment: You can see that this hangs as [open suggestion in rollup issue tracker](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/349). So I guess it is not possible.

Comment: Thanks! I saw that one. I thought maybe there's a different method such as TypeScript `namespaces` but I tried those as well and they didn't work either. Also an indicator that it's not possible is RxJS 6, removing all prefixes?

Comment: You can achieve that if you augument classes for development. Say that you have entryfile for production and you want add some additional methods for development that should not be present in production code. So you can import base file, subclass, add additional methods and and use it in develpment rollup config.. But thats only my opinion..